# "ng-switch on" and "ng-switch" difference

Tags: angularjs, ng-switch

I was studiously reading the AngularJS API reference for the [ngSwitch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) directive when I came to that part :

> place an expression on the on="..." attribute (or the ng-switch="..."
>   attribute)

So of course I was wondering why there are two ways to place the expression since both of them seems to work the same way.

```
<div ng-switch="expression">
<div ng-switch on="expression">
```

I assume there is a reason but I do not find anything for now.

Plunker to test : http://plnkr.co/edit/VAq1t4744bnNC6RgZtEn?p=preview

Answer (score 13):

There is no difference. 
You can check the sources of ng-switch directive
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngSwitch.js

```
var watchExpr = attr.ngSwitch || attr.on
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was expecting.
So I just doesn't understand why there are two syntax. Not really usefull and potentially confusing :)

Comment: One use for the on syntax is that you can use ng-switch as a tag: `<ng-switch on="...">`